# resetting a dropdown combobox c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I've created a form that allows for seat booking it has two dropdown menus and a label that changes showing them what seats they have booked. the label resets when I press the reset button but the drop down menus don't, they stay on the selected seats e.g. one menu saying "A" and the other saying "4" I need these to reset to blank can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace courseworkTask3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string temp = comboBox1.Text;
        int dropBox1enter;
        if (int.TryParse(temp, out dropBox1enter))
        {

        }


        int i = 0;
        int seatsFound = 0;
        int maxFoundSeats = 0;
        int maxFoundSeatsStart = 0;
        int maxFoundSeatsEnd = 0;
        bool[] rowA = new bool[10];
        rowA[0] = true;
        rowA[1] = true;
        rowA[2] = false;
        rowA[3] = false;
        rowA[4] = false;
        rowA[5] = true;
        rowA[6] = true;
        rowA[7] = false;
        rowA[8] = false;
        rowA[9] = false;

        bool[] rowB = new bool[10];
        rowB[0] = true;
        rowB[1] = false;
        rowB[2] = false;
        rowB[3] = false;
        rowB[4] = false;
        rowB[5] = true;
        rowB[6] = true;
        rowB[7] = false;
        rowB[8] = false;
        rowB[9] = false;

        bool[] rowC = new bool[10];
        rowC[0] = true;
        rowC[1] = false;
        rowC[2] = false;
        rowC[3] = false;
        rowC[4] = false;
        rowC[5] = true;
        rowC[6] = true;
        rowC[7] = false;
        rowC[8] = false;
        rowC[9] = false;

        bool[] rowD = new bool[10];
        rowD[0] = true;
        rowD[1] = false;
        rowD[2] = false;
        rowD[3] = false;
        rowD[4] = false;
        rowD[5] = true;
        rowD[6] = true;
        rowD[7] = false;
        rowD[8] = false;
        rowD[9] = false;

        bool[] rowE = new bool[10];
        rowE[0] = true;
        rowE[1] = false;
        rowE[2] = false;
        rowE[3] = false;
        rowE[4] = false;
        rowE[5] = true;
        rowE[6] = true;
        rowE[7] = false;
        rowE[8] = false;
        rowE[9] = false;

        if (comboBox2.Text == "A")
        {
            while (i < 10 && maxFoundSeats < dropBox1enter)
            {
                if (rowA[i] == false)
                {
                    seatsFound++;
                    if (seatsFound > maxFoundSeats)
                    {
                        maxFoundSeats = seatsFound;
                        maxFoundSeatsStart = 1 + i - seatsFound;
                        maxFoundSeatsEnd = i;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    seatsFound = 0;
                }
                i++;
            } if (maxFoundSeats == dropBox1enter)
            {
                label4.Text = "Booked for " + maxFoundSeats + " seat(s) in row A starting, seat " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to seat " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";

            }
            else
            {
                label4.Text = "The seats you have selected are unavailable. @The maximum available is " + maxFoundSeats + " in row A From " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";
                label4.Text = label4.Text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (comboBox2.Text == "B")
            {
                while (i < 10 && maxFoundSeats < dropBox1enter)
                {
                    if (rowB[i] == false)
                    {
                        seatsFound++;
                        if (seatsFound > maxFoundSeats)
                        {
                            maxFoundSeats = seatsFound;
                            maxFoundSeatsStart = 1 + i - seatsFound;
                            maxFoundSeatsEnd = i;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        seatsFound = 0;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (maxFoundSeats == dropBox1enter)
                {
                    label4.Text = "Booked for " + maxFoundSeats + " seat(s) in row B starting, seat " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to seat " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";

                }
                else
                {
                    label4.Text = "The seats you have selected are unavailable. @The maximum available is " + maxFoundSeats + " in row B From " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";
                    label4.Text = label4.Text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (comboBox2.Text == "C")
                {
                    while (i < 10 && maxFoundSeats < dropBox1enter)
                    {
                        if (rowC[i] == false)
                        {
                            seatsFound++;
                            if (seatsFound > maxFoundSeats)
                            {
                                maxFoundSeats = seatsFound;
                                maxFoundSeatsStart = 1 + i - seatsFound;
                                maxFoundSeatsEnd = i;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            seatsFound = 0;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (maxFoundSeats == dropBox1enter)
                    {
                        label4.Text = "Booked for " + maxFoundSeats + " seat(s) in row C starting, seat " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to seat " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label4.Text = "The seats you have selected are unavailable. @The maximum available is " + maxFoundSeats + " in row C From " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";
                        label4.Text = label4.Text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (comboBox2.Text == "D")
                    {
                        while (i < 10 && maxFoundSeats < dropBox1enter)
                        {
                            if (rowD[i] == false)
                            {
                                seatsFound++;
                                if (seatsFound > maxFoundSeats)
                                {
                                    maxFoundSeats = seatsFound;
                                    maxFoundSeatsStart = 1 + i - seatsFound;
                                    maxFoundSeatsEnd = i;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                seatsFound = 0;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        if (maxFoundSeats == dropBox1enter)
                        {
                            label4.Text = "Booked for " + maxFoundSeats + " seat(s) in row D starting, seat " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to seat " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label4.Text = "The seats you have selected are unavailable. @The maximum available is " + maxFoundSeats + " in row D From " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";
                            label4.Text = label4.Text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (comboBox2.Text == "E")
                        {
                            while (i < 10 && maxFoundSeats < dropBox1enter)
                            {
                                if (rowE[i] == false)
                                {
                                    seatsFound++;
                                    if (seatsFound > maxFoundSeats)
                                    {
                                        maxFoundSeats = seatsFound;
                                        maxFoundSeatsStart = 1 + i - seatsFound;
                                        maxFoundSeatsEnd = i;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    seatsFound = 0;
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                            if (maxFoundSeats == dropBox1enter)
                            {
                                label4.Text = "Booked for " + maxFoundSeats + " seat(s) in row E starting, seat " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to seat " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                label4.Text = "The seats you have selected are unavailable. @The maximum available is " + maxFoundSeats + " in row E From " + maxFoundSeatsStart + " to " + maxFoundSeatsEnd + ".";
                                label4.Text = label4.Text.Replace("@", System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                          }
                        } //end E
                    } //end D
                } //end C
            } 
        }

    private void dropBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void dropBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text != null && comboBox2.Text != null)

        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label4.Text = "";


    } 


    }

}
```

Comment: set combobox.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: SelectedText = null should also work (if it was whole objects as datasource then SelectedValue but so its only SelectedText).  That is in addition to rohits Selected index.

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow. Man, it will take half of my day to read this code, please localize the problem

Comment: Also @ the originalposter if you post a longer code (especially there but also generally) it would be quite good if you use names for buttons,... which say something about which button it is and what it does. that improves readability of code quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rohit Prakash pointed out in the comments to your question, setting the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox to -1 will reset any selections to the Combobox:

(I'm assuming "button2" is your Reset button, you should really name your controls more appropriately)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    label4.Text = "";
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; 
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;      
}
```

Comment: thanks guys can see where I went wrong now thanks for your help!